# How to group documents by a field and list unequal values with custom reduce function with CouchDB view

Tags: view, mapreduce, couchdb, reduce

I have 1000's of staff documents in CouchDB, which in a simplified format look like so:

```
{
    "_id": "1111",
    "departmentId": "dept_A",
    "siteId": "SITE_1"
}
{
    "_id": "2222",
    "departmentId": "dept_B",
    "siteId": "SITE_1"
}
{
    "_id": "3333",
    "departmentId": "dept_C",
    "siteId": "SITE_1"
}
{
    "_id": "4444",
    "departmentId": "dept_C",
    "siteId": "SITE_1"
}
{
    "_id": "5555",
    "departmentId": "dept_A",
    "siteId": "SITE_2"
}
{
    "_id": "6666",
    "departmentId": "dept_A",
    "siteId": "SITE_2"
}
```

I have a view like this:

```
function (doc) {
    if (doc.departmentId && doc.siteId) {
        emit(doc.siteId, doc.departmentId);
    }
}
```

Which will display the data like so:

```
{"SITE_1": "dept_A"}
{"SITE_1": "dept_B"}
{"SITE_1": "dept_C"}
{"SITE_1": "dept_C"}
{"SITE_2": "dept_A"}
{"SITE_2": "dept_A"}
```

However, I would like to use a custom reduce function with a CouchDB view to group the data like so:

```
{"SITE_1": ["dept_A", "dept_B", "dept_C"]}
{"SITE_2": ["dept_A"]}
```

A custom reduce function for a CouchDB view starts like so:

```
function (keys, values, rereduce) {

}
```

Comment: `siteId: 1` is not included in your output is it a typo or you're not adding by any rule, ?

Comment: typo thanks for the spot

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [**Set**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
let arr= [{"_id": "1111","departmentId": "dept_A","siteId": "SITE_1"},{"_id": "2222","departmentId": "dept_B","siteId": "SITE_1"},{"_id": "3333","departmentId": "dept_C","siteId": "SITE_1"},{"_id": "4444","departmentId": "dept_C","siteId": "SITE_1"},{"_id": "5555","departmentId": "dept_A","siteId": "SITE_2"},{"_id": "6666","departmentId": "dept_A","siteId": "SITE_2"}]

let final = arr.reduce((op, {siteId, departmentId}) => {
  op[siteId] = op[siteId] || new Set()
  op[siteId].add(departmentId)
  return op
},{})

console.log(...final['SITE_1'])
console.log(...final['SITE_2'])
```

Comment: This js is too modern for a CouchDB reduce. It won’t work with “let” amongst other things.

Comment: @xpqz this code can be easily converted into a `for` loop and `var` for such cases